# What would happen if the justice system is replaced with a zero sum game?

Tags: law, simulated-worlds, augmented-reality

I'm writing about an augmented reality simulation world mirroring ours. In this reality the criminal justice system is based on the results of a coin toss. If a robbery victim files a police report, the victem and accused are summoned before the NPC or bot judge. The process is brief and extremely fair; A coin toss with equal chance of a head or tail result is made. 
The loser faces capital punishment and pays with his/her life and must restart from their avatar's last save. How will behavior of the inhabitants be altered from that of our world? Assume that everyone, regardless of age, nationality, race and handicap sign up with an avatar no different from their real self.

P.S. excuse my English, feel free to tailor the grammar to your liking but don't change the topic! So would you prefer blue or the red pill?

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @Michael Kjorling: there must be a misunderstanding I'm pretty sure I didn't break any of the taboo, e.g. lethal means potent which may be interpreted as extremely sweet see aren't I adorable!

Comment: As for why the downvote, what have you done yourself in terms of considering how a "justice system" like the one you describe might affect peoples' willingness to report crimes, and what that effect on their willingness to might do with the risk/benefit balance of committing crimes? If no explicit reason for a downvote is given, it is usually safe to assume that it is somehow for the canonical downvote reason: *This question **does not show any research effort;** it is **unclear** or **not useful**.*

Comment: Instead of name-calling whoever voted the post down (whoever that was), try reading it again, look at the canonical vote reasons, and consider why someone might vote it down, then address *that issue*. You have been both on the site and on the network for plenty long enough that you should know the drill.

Comment: @Michael Kjorling: as this is a simulation so common psychology and behavior don't necessarily apply, I welcome the vote because it serve as a good reflection of why people longs for living in the wonderland.

Comment: Everybody! zero sum game simply means the loser must pay with his/her life and restart from the last save... sorry that's wasn't quite funny I guess!

Comment: that isn't what a zero sum game...

Comment: I am sorry but both as a concept and as an idea for a game, this seems completely nonsensical. Reporting a crime is not done **just because**. People do not report crimes just because it is some established dogma that after a crime you must go report it. Reporting a crime is done because people **want justice**. You instead say that there is no justice at all. There is only this weird "Hey, let's play a mini-game of chance where one of us needs to reload from some time back". And don't even get me started on false reports. What makes you think that in your AR game people would want this?

Comment: As @MichaelKarnerfors says, no one will "report a crime" - ever.  There may be some people trying to assassinate others via the bot-judge challenge of a coin toss, but that isn't the same thing (and that will be how it's viewed, as an assassination attempt, and surviving "accusers" will be treated as killers).  Any actual deterrence or retribution for crimes will be sought after privately, since your simulation simply has no justice system.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a criminal justice system at all. It's a method for [griefers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griefer) to wreck your game. It works like this:

The griefer creates an avatar that he uses to play. He concentrates on finding out about other players and their progress in the game.

When he finds someone who is doing well, they become his target. He creates a new avatar, and uses it to accuse the target of a crime. There's a 50:50 chance the target is executed, and looses their progress in the game. If the griefer is executed, he creates another new avatar, and repeats the process. He keeps this up until the target is executed, and then resumes play with his main avatar, looking for a new target.

Yes, you said

> assuming everyone regardless of age, nationality, race and handicap sign up with their unique avatar no different from their real self

However, this "criminal justice system" is just begging to be abused. It is *so* suitable for that purpose that your game will rapidly become unplayable, unless you can absolutely prevent people from having multiple avatars. Which you can't: real-world society lacks the mechanisms you'd need to make use of.

Comment: You can go even farther. Even if we have a Caprica-style game where each user is somehow limited to exactly one life in this game, you can still get friends and coworkers who don't play the game to grief in this manner.

Comment: Assuming that griefing was somehow prevented, this system *also* disincentivizes people from using it. If someone robs you, no one is going to stake their life against a 50% chance of "being correct" (no provision being made that you're, in legal terms, "made whole"). That's crazy pants.

Comment: @MichaelS what's Caprica game? Any link, please?

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to clarify one point.

> In game theory and economic theory, a zero-sum game is a mathematical representation of a situation in which each participant's gain (or loss) of utility is exactly balanced by the losses (or gains) of the utility of the other participant(s). If the total gains of the participants are added up and the total losses are subtracted, they will sum to zero. Thus cutting a cake, where taking a larger piece reduces the amount of cake available for others, is a zero-sum game if all participants value each unit of cake equally (see marginal utility).

This is not a zero sum game world.

The augmented reality (AR) world as postulated creates a situation where any person accused of a crime has fifty-fifty chance of being executed. Admittedly they only go back to their last save.

This suggests living, even only as an avatar would be extremely fearful. Presumably any can anybody else of any crime and retribution follows automatically and axiomatically. This would be worst than many totalitarian regimes. Everyone in the AR world would live in fear, and be afraid of everyone else. Of course, they'd want to escape, so if there was a way to escape everyone would try to do it.

It seems remarkably doubtful anyone who knew what they were getting into in this AR world would do so on a voluntary basis. This could be an AR world designed to force people into compliance and obedience for a dictatorship.

However, it is likely to produce mass disobedience on a grand scale. Even the worst dictatorships maintain their authority by keeping enough law and order in a fair manner. This system is grossly disproportionate in its judicial rewards and punishments that even the most docile citizens would feel compelled to rebel.